# React : Get data of a user_id with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list created using react and fetching data using axios as the following

https://codesandbox.io/s/old-worker-6k4s6

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  

  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => {
        setList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
 

  return (
    <div>
    

      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.title}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see all the titles are shown. **How can I for example show titles of only `userID` = 2 ?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already an [answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @Martin The fact that an answer to a question exists somewhere *other* than SO, is *not* a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update like this:

```
{list.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.userId === 2) {
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.title}</div>
            </li>
          );
        }
        return null;
      })}
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-oskar-x0r5t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I needed to add something in the axios function.